# Solidity Basic：an example of Mapping Types from Solidity doc

Tags: inheritance, mapping, solidity, smartcontracts

I'm self learning Solidity, forgive my stupid questions please, I'm an absolute beginner.The following ss is from the doc[https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.22/types.html#mapping-types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxbgN.png)
My question is: what does the 2nd part of the code mean? I opened the code in Remix:[ss from Remix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fg3Hz.png)
As you can see, the deployed contract has nothing to do with the 2nd part of the code. Especially, I'm totally confused about this line:  MappingExample m = new MappingExample();
where does "m" come from? It seems to be inherited from Contract MappingExample, but what's the meaning of that line? I need your help. I tried to find an answer on web, but I don't know the proper keyword ... I’d appreciate it if you give me a link to get more relevant information.

I goggled "mapping", "solidity contract inheritance", unfortunately, I didn't get what I want. The search results were just common examples of the usage of Mapping Type in Solidity, with no detailed explanation for beginners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two contracts in the picture you provided.
Mapping is a data structure like a dictionary in Python and the hash map in C++, java, etc...

The first contract has mapping that gets an `address` and returns a `uint`.
It also has a function `update` that gets a `uint newBalance` and assigns it to the `msg.sender` which is the address of the message sender.

The second contract wants to use the first contract's data(here, mapping balances).
It has a function `f` that does the following:

1. It creates a new `mappingExample` instance and names it `m`(the programmer was able to name it anything else, It's just a name.)
2. Using `m.update()` it interacts with the `update` function of the `mappingExample` instance it created in the first line.
3. Returns the balance of the contract(mappingUser contract) by reading from `balances` of the instance `m`(Notice: first contract did not have a balances function but because the `balances` variable has a `public` modifier we can use it a function from outside to read from it.)

PS1: It doesn't have anything to do with inheritance; It's just creating an instance and using it.

PS2: Your question was not stupid. You are just learning. Take your time.